# Set Variable To Header Text Column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a workbook that is never received in the same format.  To prevent manual intervention, I need to capture the Column that the text `employee` is in.  For example, if the text is in column O - I would execute the below, but I would need the `Cells(i,"O")` to be changed based off the cell that contains the text `employee`

```
Sub DoThis()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "O").Value) Then 
        'stuff here
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the header always just `employee`? Is that the only text in the cell?

Comment: @Jordan - yes the header text I need to locate is always employee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Find` method and get the column of the cell that `employee` is found in to use in `Cells` :

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoThis()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- change to your sheet
        lngCol = .Rows(1).Find("employee").Column '<-- assumes header in Row 1
        For i = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(3).Row To 2 Step -1
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, lngCol).Value) Then
                'stuff here
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` method

```
Cells.Find("employee")
```

This will find the cell in the range specified (here I've used `Cells` but I'd narrow this down to your range) and it will return the cell that contains the text "employee". You can then reference this as a `Range` object i.e. use `.Row` to get the row number or `.Column` to get the column number